# sorting array in tableview

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios, uitableview, sorting

I have an array and a tableview that gets its data from the array. When I view the tableview on the iPhone, its, ofc, not sorted, and its listed as I have written them.

I wanna sort my array in the tableview, so they aren't listed like this:

- D
- A
- G
- F
- S

but listed like this instead:

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E
- Etc...

How can I do this?

**Here is my array:**

```
stationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[stationList addObject:@"A"];
[stationList addObject:@"B"];
[stationList addObject:@"C"];
```

How do I load the array into my tableview array?
**Loading the array:**

```
NSString *cellValue = [stationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

Comment: Read the API doc for NSMutableArray - there are methods for sorting. Or Google for "sort nsmutablearray".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[stationList sortUsingFunction:compareLetters context:whateveryouwant_ornil]`

And

```
NSComparisonResult compareLetters(id t1, id t2, void* context) {

      do the tests you want beetween t1 and t2, and return the result
      like :

      if (the test) return NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedSame
}
```

In your example, you should do :

```
NSMutableArray stationList = [[NSMutableArray array];
[stationList addObject:@"A"];
[stationList addObject:@"B"];
[stationList addObject:@"C"];
[stationList sortUsingFunction:compareLetters context:nil];

NSComparisonResult compareLetters(id t1, id t2, void* context) {
      return [t1 compare:t2];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "do the tests you want beetween t1 and t2, and" ?? what should i do test for ? sorry if its a stupid question

Comment: @Patrick R : this depends on the things you want to sort. If you sort strings, call [t1 compare:t2], if you test integers, test t1 == t2, if you test custom objects, you're the only one that know what must be tested, like t1.age and t2.age, ...

Comment: @Patrick R : the compare function will be automaticaly be called for mutiple pairs of your array values, untill the whole thing is sorted. You just need to test and return how the 2 params are sorted each other

Comment: im testing for strings.. soo.. it needs to be
"do [t1 compare:t2]" ? sorry, but im not that into objective-c :/

Comment: @Patrick R : see my edit. the compare function beetween NSString already return NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedSame. So it's easy. For such a simple case, I believe there is a more simplier way but this one works, and can be reused for other type of contents. Do you know the AppKiDo software ? If you don't you should take a look at it, it would be a great help.

Comment: arh okay, i see what you've done, making a bit more sence now :) but no dont know appKiDo, so ill take a look at it :) thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: just downloaded the AppKiDo, and it looks nice :) ive tryed replaceing the context "whateveryouwant"_ornil with my array  stationList but im getting an error: "nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable" in the NSComparisonResult.. and in the "sortUsingFunction:compareLetters" im getting an error that stationList_ornil aint set ? whats the problem here ? ive looked it up and cant figger out what went wrong :/

Comment: @Patrick R : just put nil. It can be used if you want some extra feature that does not seems to apply here. the compare function will be automaticaly be called for mutiple pairs of your array values, untill the whole thing is sorted. You just need to test and return how the 2 params are sorted each other

Comment: the nil worked :) but the error nested is still there.. what wrong ?

Comment: @Patrick R : See my edit. Perhaps it's because of your array init.

Comment: @Patrick R : If you agree with my solution, could you accept it and vote for it please ?

Comment: Ya sure :) thanks a lot for the help.. finnily figger out what was wrong.. i pasted the function inside the viewdid load >.<

Answer (score 2):

Go to the below tutorial for sorting `NSArray`, they have explained the basic technique to sort a `NSArray`.

You can also download the sample code provided in the end of tutorial. [Here is the link.](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/02/tutorial-tips-sorting-filtering-filter-nsmutablearray-and-sorting-nsmutablearray-by-ascending-or-objects-items-or-specified-key-or-key-value-or-by-nsnumber/)

Answer (score 0):

You can user some simple steps. Which I am using. I am not sure its perfect in context of memory consumption. But its working with me in my application.

Here record is NSMutableArray.
Columnname is on Which Coulmn you want sorting. In my case I had more than one column to sort. And Sorting takes BOOL data.

After soring I am reloading my TableView.

```
    NSSortDescriptor * frequencyDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:columnName ascending:YES];

    NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frequencyDescriptor, nil];
    [record sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
    [columnName release];
    [frequencyDescriptor release];
    [myTableView reloadData];
```

I hope this is fine. Do let me know if I can make it better